# How update CID font from Ghostscript

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert some PDFs files with

```
gs -SDEVICE=tiffg4 -r600x600 -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sOutputFile=_LOTE_51168_01.tiff -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH *.pdf
```

easy example, but when execute the line, got the next error

```
Can't find CID font "MS-Gothic".
Substituting CID font /Adobe-Japan1 for /MS-Gothic, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Japan1" is not provided either. Will exit with error.
Error: /undefined in findresource
Operand stack:
--dict:8/17(L)--   F1   10.5   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   MS-Gothic       --dict:11/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   CIDFontObject   --dict:9/9(L)--   --dict:9/9(L)--   Adobe-Japan1
Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:26/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Looking in the web, find that I have to update de CID font, but don't know how, I read the page http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#CIDFonts but is kind of complicated, someone know or someone do something like this, or know from some tutorial to do this, I'm realy appreciate if help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more up to date version of Ghostscript, the current version (9.18) ships with a fallback CIDFont which **might** work. Otherwise you will need to add a CIDFont to the list of fonts whch Ghostscript knows about. It needs to be either a genuine CIDFont or a TrueType font which can (within limits) be used as a replacement for a missing CIDFont.

Its not going to be possible to give a step-by-step instruction because the various Linux distributions package Ghostscript differently and the version you are using is very old (at least 6 years old now). I don't recall what would need to be done with a version that old, and the instructions on the website are probably not compatible with such an old version, they relate to the current version.

You want the section in the documentation entitled "CID Font substitution" (because you are defining a substitute for a missing font) and then 'Explicit DICFont substitution', almost certainly 'format 2'

Comment: Thanks @KenS is true that you say, I'm realy appreciate if help me with a manual or something like this, a just update the Ghostscript to the last version 9.18 in other server for testing, and a got the same error.

Comment: There is no manual, the HTML help files are it. I can't comment any further without seeing an example file, a command line and a transcript of stdout. I noted in my answer above which section of the documentation to look at, you will of course need to source a suitable font to use as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Following experiments for CJK integration in TeX Live 2015, a tutorial on the use of CID fonts with Ghostscript may be found at

https://www.preining.info/blog/2015/04/setting-up-cid-fonts-for-ghostscript-technical-notes/

Beware: Ghostscript must be compiled with

```
./configure --disable-compile-inits
```

otherwise the directories where the various fonts, symlinks and config files must be put will be built in the gs binary hence unaccessible. (Maybe this is the default on Linux, I'm from the Mac and can't tell.)

A script for creating all the required files may be found at

https://www.preining.info/blog/software-projects/cjk-fonts-ghostscript/

Hope this helps!